# Javascript checking current time with planned time

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to get an if statement true in my javascript. I track the current time with a `setInterval(function)`. In this Interval I compare a planned datetime with the current datetime:

first I checked it with a simple `if(date1 == date2)` but I found on the internet you should use `getTime()` (found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript))
I got this now but it still gives a false when the values are equal:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    console.log("current time: " + currentTime);
    console.log("end production time: " + endProdTimeMachine2);
    console.log(currentTime.getTime() === endProdTimeMachine2.getTime());
    
    if(currentTime.getTime() === endProdTimeMachine2.getTime())
    {
         console.log("I'm in!!!");
    }
},1000);
```

When I run this code, my console give this as a result:[image]

So what is going wrong? is it something with the interval?

Comment: Did you try verifying what the actual numerical values are that currentTime.getTime() and endProductTimeMachine2.getTime() give? It should give you clear numbers that would make for simpler debugging?

Comment: @Marcus ah ye, it's about miliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that milliseconds do not match in your check, because the start of setInterval can be at any millisecond:

```
if(currentTime.getTime() === endProdTimeMachine2.getTime())
```

You can change your code, and check only if this timestamp is bigger, and afterwards clear the timeout, to stop further checks:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(currentTime.getTime() >= endProdTimeMachine2.getTime()) {
         console.log("I'm in!!!");
         clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Well it kinda needs to roll through the interval function. So I have to check if the currentTime is between endprodtime +1000 and -1000 or smthing

Comment: Hm, but the interval will run each 1 sec, this will guarantee that it will execute at max time - endprodtime + 999, depending at which millisecond setInterval had started.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem:

A `1000ms` interval doesn't guarantee that you'll read it in the exact same millisecond, in fact it's quite improbable.

You're running that function each second but reading milliseconds, so you're open to a `999ms` displacement.

## Solution:

To avoid that, compare it with `endProduction` in a `999ms` range, so you'll know that you're close enough to that exact moment in time.

Example with a range between `-499ms` and `+500ms`:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    console.log("current time: " + currentTime);
    console.log("end production time: " + endProdTimeMachine2);

    var currentTimeMs = currentTime.getTime();
    var endProdTimeMs = endProdTimeMachine2.getTime();
    
    if (currentTimeMs >= (endProdTimeMs - 499) && currentTimeMs <= (endProdTimeMs + 500) )
    {
         console.log("I'm in!!!");
    }
},1000);
```

Otherwise, if you need it after, change the comparison to:

```
if (currentTimeMs >= endProdTimeMs && currentTimeMs <= (endProdTimeMs + 999) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example:

```
var d1 = "abcd";
var d2 = "abcd";
console.log(d1 == d2); //prints true

d1 = new Date();
d2 = new Date(d1);
console.log(d1 == d2); //prints false

d1 = d2;
console.log(d1 == d2); //prints true
```

To compare numerical values with `getTime()`:

```
d1 = new Date();
d2 = new Date(d1);
console.log(d1.getTime() == d2.getTime()); //prints true
```

Comment: I already do that..? I already mentioned that in my question (you even gave the same link as I did)

Comment: It's about the milliseconds